# Centrally symmetric polytopes can be divided into 2 subsets of smaller diameter

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry

I need to show that this is true for any dimension $d\ge1$.

So far I can show it for triangle and rectangle in $R2$ and for cube in $R3$.
But I fail to show it for circle, and sphere. I even think that it is impossible.

If it is possible I think there is Barsuk or Hadwiger's theorem is used.
But I can't figure out how.

Can you please help me to prove it for dimension $d\ge1$?

EDIT: Circle and sphere turn out not to be polytope, my mistake.

But is there a mathematical way to show that polytopes of dimension $d$ can be divided into $2$ parts with smaller diameter?

Comment: Circle and sphere aren't polytopes, are they?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry it has to have flat surface right ?

Comment: Yes, it's the higher-dimensional analogue of a polygon.